# AES 256 encryption and decryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS.How does AES 256 encryption work in s3 bucket?I have uploaded a file in to my s3 bucket and encrypted it with AES 256 Encryption.But i'm able to download the file easily.Is that the expected scenario?It should be asking me to decrypt right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, thats works as expected. When you enable encryption on S3, it will store data encrypted form at rest. When you download or view files it will decrypt automatically.

Overall idea to encrypt at rest is that if someone steals hardrive from AWS data centre they will not be able to get access to data as it is encrypted.